# Taylor series representation for a Riemannian hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

This is Exercise 8.5 in Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature*.

Suppose $M\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is a hypersurface with the induced metric. Let $p\in M$, and let $\kappa_1,\dots,\kappa_n$ denote the principal curvatures of $M$ at $p$ with respect to some choice of unit normal.

> 1. Show that $M$ can be approximated locally by the quadratic polynomial $\frac{1}{2} h$ [the scalar second fundamental form] in the
>      following sense: There are Euclidean coordinates $(x,y)=(x^1,\dots,
>     x^n, y)$ centered at $p$ such that $M$ is described locally by an
>      equation of the form $y=f(x)$, where the second-order Taylor series of
>      $f$ at the origin is 
>      $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\kappa_1(x^1)^2)+\cdots+\kappa_n(x^n)^2)+O(|x|^3).$$
> 2. If $n=2$, show that $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ are equal to the minimum and maximum signed Euclidean curvatures of $M$-geodesics
>      passing through $p$, and also to the minimum and maximum signed
>      Euclidean curvatures of plane curves obtained by intersection $M$ with
>      planes orthogonal to $T_p M$.

I'm stuck on the first part. Let's consider the problem with $n=2$, as the ideas here almost certainly generalize. My idea is to place $p$ at the origin with the normal vector pointing along the $z$-axis. Then we should have a map:
$(x,y)\rightarrow (x,y,f(x,y))$
given by projection along the $z$-axis. But I'm having trouble making this precise. In particular, I don't see why this must be well-defined (the projection could never intersect the submanifold) or smooth. I suspect this ultimately ends up being some inverse function theorem trick.

But this not the whole story. Recall the $\kappa_i$ are defined as eigenvalues of the operator $s$ on $T_pM$, so we probably need to do a change of coordinates on $(x,y)$ to ensure the $\kappa_i$ are sent to the eigenvectors $E_i$.

If that map is given, clearly the way to proceed is to do a Taylor expansion and show we get the desired coefficients. It seems that the way we chose the coordinate system should force all the first derivatives to be zero. I am lost on how to get the second order terms.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have sketched an attempt in the comments that I think works.

Comment: You're on the right track. Pick $v_1$ and $v_2$ to be tangent vectors that are eigenvectors of $s$ for the evalues $k_i$; then $v_1, v_2, n$ is an orthonormal frame for 3-space, which you might as well, by change of coords, assume look like $e_1, e_2, e_3$. Why is projection along $z$ a nice map? Because it's well approximated by "normal coordinates" at $p$.

Comment: @JohnHughes Ah, I see. I think there are two steps here. First, show we can get coordinates that look like $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,f(x,y))$ and such that the tangent space at $p=(0,0,0)$ is the x-y plane with the tangent vectors $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ identified with the eigenvectors $E_i$. I think this can be done with normal coordinates. Second, use the fact that the acceleration of any unit speed geodesic is entirely normal to the surface with magnitude calculable in terms of the $\kappa_i$.

Comment: So to find the first derivative, for example, we look at $a(t)=(t,0,f(t,0))$ and note that since $a'(0)$ gets pushed forward to $E_1$, it lies in the tangent space at $0$ and hence the x-y plane, so $f_x(0,0)=0$ and similarly for $f_y$. For the second derivatives $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ we can use the fact about acceleration I mentioned. For $f_{xy}$ I think that we can take the curve $(t,t, f(t,t))$ and differentiate twice, using the fact about acceleration again to find that $f_{xy}=0$.

Comment: For the last bit I am using the fact that the scalar fundamental form $h(X,Y)$ looks like $\kappa_1 X^1 Y^1 + \kappa_2 X^2 Y^2$ and $\gamma''(t)=h(\gamma',\gamma')N$.

Comment: It sounds as if you're on the right track, yes (although I have not worked through the details or done this problem myself).